# Randomly re-place a div element when an animated div crosses coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am making a simple web game where can use arrow keys to move a div around the page with the goal of colliding it with another div. The second div will then be randomly placed somewhere else on the page. My question is, how can I change to following code to relocate the second div apon collision?

I have code that does this when the div is clicked

```
$('#test').click(function() {
  var docHeight = $(document).height(),
    docWidth = $(document).width(),
    $div = $('#test'),
    divWidth = $div.width(),
    divHeight = $div.height(),
    heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
    widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

$div.css({
    left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
    top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax )
});
});
```

I am looking to do this in jquery, js, or angular. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at these jQuery plugins: https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/collision/

Comment: As it's stated this question seems too broad for SO perhaps narrow it down to something like how can I tell if two divs overlap each other if each is positioned absolutely within a container.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like https://api.jquery.com/offset/ :

```
$('moving_div').click(function(){ // or the action you make the div move

    if ( $('#moving').offset().left == $('#target').offset().left && $('#moving').offset().top == $('#target').offset().top ) {
        $('target_div').css({
          left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
          top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax )
        });
    }

});
```

like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/7seqdp3b/